# get node value from JTree event to another event button press

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jbutton

Basically want to select the node from the JTree and push the node value JTable using JButton, [for example:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D9rCQ.png)

I could able to get the node's leaf value from JTree and I want to pass the node value to the button press event, have posted the code so far have tried, please give me some directions on this, thanks

Tree event:

```
        File root = new File(System.getProperty("user.home"));
    FileTreeModel model = new FileTreeModel(root);
    JTree tree = new JTree(model);
    JScrollPane scrollpane = new JScrollPane(tree);
    scrollpane.setBounds(10, 9, 304, 730);
    frmViperManufacturingRecord.getContentPane().add(scrollpane);

    tree.addTreeSelectionListener(new TreeSelectionListener() {
        public void valueChanged(TreeSelectionEvent e) {
            File node = (File)e.getPath().getLastPathComponent();

            //System.out.println("You selected " + node);
            if (!node.isFile()) {
                JFrame frame = new JFrame();
                JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(frame, "Please select the valid file to Add Files", "Not Valid File",JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE );
            }
        }
    });
```

Button event:

```
// Add files button
    JButton btnAddFiles_1 = new JButton("Add Files");
    btnAddFiles_1.setMnemonic('A');
    btnAddFiles_1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
            System.out.println("You...."  );

            final String[] columnNames = {"Sl.no.", "File Name",};
            final String[][] data = {
                    {"01.", node, },};
            table_2.setModel(new DefaultTableModel(data, columnNames));
            frmViperManufacturingRecord.getContentPane().add(table_2);
            table_2.setAutoResizeMode(JTable.AUTO_RESIZE_OFF);
            table_2.getColumnModel().getColumn(0).setPreferredWidth(113);
            table_2.getColumnModel().getColumn(1).setPreferredWidth(600);
            JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(table_2);
            scrollPane.setBounds(324, 43, 713, 121);
            frmViperManufacturingRecord.getContentPane().add(scrollPane);
        }
    });
    btnAddFiles_1.setFont(new Font("Calibri", Font.BOLD, 12));
    btnAddFiles_1.setBounds(324, 9, 89, 23);
    frmViperManufacturingRecord.getContentPane().add(btnAddFiles_1);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At this line:

```
tree.addTreeSelectionListener(new TreeSelectionListener() {
    @Override // don't forget @Override annotation
    public void valueChanged(TreeSelectionEvent e) {
        File node = (File)e.getPath().getLastPathComponent(); // Look here!
        ...
    }
});
```

The variable `node` is a local variable to `valueChanged()` method which is also defined within the scope of an [Anonymous inner class](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/anonymousclasses.html) making it inaccessible from the outside:

```
btnAddFiles_1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
        ...
        final String[][] data = {{"01.", node, }}; // node is not accessible here
        ...
    }
});
```

If you want to use the selected `node` anywhere else then you need a wider scope (i.e.: a class field of enclosing class) or make a non-anonymous class implementing `TreeSelectionListener` interface and providing an appropriate getter to the selected node.

Comment: Thanks again for your help @dic19, when I make '@Override method', I get an [error](http://i.imgur.com/dZUnqXn.png), which I couldn't resolve it so I remove them.

Comment: That error may suggest two things: 1) There's no method called valueChanged()` defined in `TreeSelectionListener` (which is false) 2) Import to `javax.swing.event.TreeSelectionListener` is missing, so the IDE thinks you are trying to define a new inner class (different from standard `TreeSelectionListener`) and warns you there's no upper class method called `valueChanged()`. Just check for that import and all go well. And don't forget the wider scope/non-anonymous class advice :) @Java.beginner